# Table row expandable using recursive javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<tr onclick="removeAllDescendant(this)" parentid="@item.parentId" id="@item.id">
    <td>
    Use: <input type="checkbox" value="@item.iaId" />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    Qty: <input type="text" class="width_100" />
</td>
<td>@item.location</td>
<td>@item.qty @item.uom</td>
<td>@item.createDt</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

I have dynamically created these table rows, every row has parent-id and an id. I want to collapse all descendant row when user click in row.

Here is the javascript code-

```
function removeAllDescendant(row)
{
   var id = $(row).attr("id");
   removeRows(row, id);
}

function removeRows(row, id) {
    var tr = $(row).nextAll('tr [parentid=' + id + ']');
    if (tr.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            id = $(tr[i]).attr("id");
            alert(id);
            removeRows(tr[i], id);
        }
    }
    $(tr).remove();
}
```

Do you guys see any bug in this recursive function, for some reason this is not working in case I have more than 3 levels.

Comment: define **not working**. What errors do you get?

Comment: so I am not getting any error, recursive function is only calling first sibling at every level.

0 -> 1
1 -> 2, 3
2 -> 4, 5
3 -> 6

if I click row 0 or 1 it doesn't remove 6

Comment: Could you show the markup for a parent/child so we know what structure the JS is acting upon.

Comment: i see that you have a way to get the parent of a tablerow, but how do you get the childrens of a element?

Comment: I recursively call, so I can get all children of a row by   $(row).nextAll('tr [parentid=' + id + ']');

Comment: After debugging several times, I found what was the issue

I was using variable (i) in for loop, I should have define it for every call.
So right code will be -----------------------------

    function removeRows(row, id) {
  var tr = $(row).siblings('tr [parentid=' + id + ']');
  if (tr.length > 0) {
   for (var index = 0; index < tr.length; index++) {
    var tempId = $(tr[index]).attr("id");
    removeRows(tr[index], tempId);
   }
  }
  $(tr).remove();
 }

Works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging javascript code I found cause of the problem. I should define variable(i) for every recursive call. So corrected code is...

```
function removeRows(row, id) {
    var tr = $(row).nextAll('tr [parentid=' + id + ']');

    if (tr.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            var tempId = $(tr[i]).attr("id");
            removeRows(tr[index], tempId);
        }
    }
    $(tr).remove();
}
```

Works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided doesn't give a good idea of what you want to do, in my opinion (and the `expandMainRow` function is not defined). Anyway, if I understanded correctly, you want to make disappear all rows following the one clicked, right? (I mean, this way: http://jsfiddle.net/Polmonite/Hdaeg/ )
If that's the case you can simply do that:

```
$('table tr:not(:last-child)').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
        $(this).removeClass('clicked').nextAll('tr').show();
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('clicked').nextAll('tr').removeClass('clicked').hide();
    }
});
```

This way when you click on a row the following rows disappear, while if you re-click it they reappear. If you don't want them to reappear on click you can more simply do:

```
$('table tr').on('click',function(){
    $(this).nextAll('tr').hide();
}
```

I apologize in case I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: So I think you misinterpreted my question. It's a tree structure, I need to remove only children of the node (not all followings).